# AS3: Search for a word that is contained, among others, in a single array object?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, object

I am trying to make a program that shows the amount of travel miles a person has accumulated.  This is the function I created:

```
function showmiles(event:MouseEvent):void {

var hintEmployee1:int;
var hintEmployee2:int;

hintEmployee1 = (employee.indexOf(txtFirstname.text));
hintEmployee2 = (employee.indexOf(txtLastname.text));

if ((hintEmployee1 != -1) && (hintEmployee2 != -1))
{
trace("yes")
}
else
{
trace ("no")
}
}
```

This should work, if the array named "employee" had only one word per object.  However, I defined the employees in the array like this:

```
employee.push({firstname: Jamie, lastname: Hughes, milesweek1: 400, milesweek2: 670})
```

How do I make my program detect if the first name (entered into the text box txtFirstname) and the last name (entered into the text box txtLastname) of a person are inside of an Array Object, without the program scanning for them as a separate Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to loop over your `array` and test each `object` individually until you find a match:

```
function showmiles(event:MouseEvent):void {

    if (isEmployee(txtFirstname.text, txtLastname.text))
    {
        trace("yes")
    }
    else
    {
        trace ("no")
    }
}

function isEmployee(firstName:String, lastName:String):Boolean
{
    // I've pluralised the name of the array which is better I think
    for (var i:int = 0; i < employees.length; i ++) 
    {
        var employee:Object = employees[i]; 
        if (employee.firstname == firstName && employee.lastName == lastName)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Employee isn't in the array
    return false;
}
```

If you included the [underscore library](https://github.com/amacdougall/underscore.as) you could do this much more succinctly with the `findWhere` function:

```
// Return the first object where firstname and lastname properties match the values in the text fields
_.findWhere(employees, { firstname: txtFirstname.text, lastname: txtLastname.text });
```

I'm assuming it's just a typo, but the name values in your objects are strings and should be quoted:

```
employee.push({firstname: "Jamie", lastname: "Hughes", milesweek1: 400, milesweek2: 670})
```